# SQL CASE when with embedded CASE when stament

Tags: sql

looking for some help to correctly format SQL CASE statement that currently calculates values during insert.I added the bold CASE statement below with the intention of converting any transactions where the total eligible sale amount was less than the required @purchase_amt(30) to a static $30.

```
**(CASE WHEN (CONVERT(int, (FLOOR(sum(li.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT))) < 30 THEN 30 / @purchase_amt) * 
                         (CASE 
                            WHEN (coalesce(tpb.property_value,'-1')) = 'VIP' THEN coalesce(@tierthree,@coupon_multiplier) 
                            WHEN (coalesce(tpb.property_value,'-1')) = 'PREMIER' THEN coalesce(@tiertwo,@coupon_multiplier) 
                            WHEN (coalesce(tpb.property_value,'-1')) = 'GOLD' THEN coalesce(@tierone,@coupon_multiplier)
                            ELSE @coupon_multiplier END) ) coupon_cnt)
ELSE** 
CONVERT(int, (FLOOR(sum(li.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT))) / @purchase_amt)  * 
                         (CASE   
                             WHEN (coalesce(tpb.property_value,'-1')) = 'VIP' THEN coalesce(@tierthree,@coupon_multiplier) 
                             WHEN (coalesce(tpb.property_value,'-1')) = 'PREMIER' THEN coalesce(@tiertwo,@coupon_multiplier) 
                             WHEN (coalesce(tpb.property_value,'-1')) = 'GOLD' THEN coalesce(@tierone,@coupon_multiplier)
                             ELSE @coupon_multiplier END) coupon_cnt)
                     **END) AS coupon_cnt**
```

Comment: `THEN 30 / @purchase_amt)` Paren doesn't balance.

Comment: Looks to me like that whole common expression could be moved outside the `case`.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I combined the case to 30 and division since I was unable to call the sale_amt that is calculate on the fly. I thought by moving the case outside I was creating a common expression after the initial calculation I was running. Not sure how to format or balance the THEN 30 / @purchase_amt).

Comment: So when initially tried this approach I would update the sale_amt correctly but couldn;t call in the subsequent CASE statement where I do my calculations.                                  (CASE
                                  WHEN sum(li.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT) < 30 THEN 30
                                  ELSE sum(li.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT) END) sale_amt,

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
    WHEN FLOOR(SUM(li.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT)) < 30 THEN 30
    ELSE CAST(FLOOR(SUM(li.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT)) AS INT) 
END / @purchase_amt *
COALESCE(
    CASE tpb.property_value
        WHEN 'VIP' THEN @tierthree
        WHEN 'PREMIER' THEN @tiertwo 
        WHEN 'GOLD' THEN @tierone
    END,
    @coupon_multiplier
) AS coupon_cnt
```

Make sure you want `a / b * c` rather than `a / (b * c)`.

Comment: Thanks, you rock! That update works great. And thanks for the match check.... I didn't see your comments initially and wondered why the final values were always greater than expected.